# Using JPanel to draw straight lines and get point coordinates

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I am at a total loss right now. I haven't worked much with building GUIs in Java, I've been reading all about swing and JPanel, and I think what I am trying to do is possible, I just haven't figured out *how*.

I'm trying to build a GUI in which you can draw straight lines within a certain drawing area, I would like to be able to get the start/endpoint coordinates in order to perform some math with those points. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

I will leave the code to you so here is the algorithm:
1.  Create a `JFrame` and add a `JPanel` to it.
2.  Add a mouse listener for the `JPanel`
3.  Every time the mouse is pressed, get the x and y of the click. (starting points)
4.  When the mouse is dragged , record x and y continuously.
5.  When mouse is released, record the x and y. (ending points)
6. You could either use the `drawLine()` method of `Graphics` class  or use `draw()` of `Graphics2D` in this case you will need a `Line2D.Double` -- the arguments remain the same - start x, start y, end x and end y

---

here is an image to explain a lil bit better:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Start with [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).

Basically, you going to need a mouse listener to monitor the user interaction with your panel, check out [How to write mouse listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more infor still.

Depending on your needs, if you need to maintain all the click points of the user, you would need to store them in something like a `List`, or if you just need to know the start and end points, the you just need a couple of `Point` objects.

You would be able to use these to paint onto your surface and performing your required calculations.

Remember, in this context, the points are contextual to the container they were generated on. That is 0x0 will be the top left of the container

**Updated**

You could also take advantage of the Shape API, using a `Line2D` to represent the two points. This would make it easier to distinguish between distinct lines/points

Comment: Hello, we meet again! I left him the algo - let him code himself. That way he will learn better :)

Comment: @LittleChild Trail by coding, I like the way you think ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks so much. Both your answers are basically what I was looking for!

Comment: @CSC I have added an image. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is harder than just "draw straight lines with (x1,y1) and (x2, y2)" approach.

You need a `Line`(your custom) object that is dynamically created and placed on the `JPanel` which is listening for `MouseEvent`s The canvas area being the `JPanel` itself. You also need to separate the MODEL from the VIEW so that your custom canvas `JPanel` will draw itself properly with an override for `paintComponent()`

The question is slightly vague, so I can't provide any code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the mouse listener on JPanel.

then:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
if(click==1){
int x1=me.getX();
int y1=me.getY();
click=click+1;
}
else{
int x2=me.getX();
int y2=me.getY();
click=1;
}
}


drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

To draw line with mouse move you can also add mouse motion listener.