# Make a line point towards the mouse

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouse, point

How do I make a line point towards the mouse?

I am trying to make a line(Graphics2d) point towards the mouse cursor in java. Instead of pointing towards the cursor, it points the opposite way (if the cursor is to the left, the line points to the right, same for the Y axis). Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
public void paintChildren(Graphics g){
Graphics g2d2 = (Graphics)g;
int centerX = 16;
int centerY = 16;
deltaX = mouseX - centerX;
deltaY = mouseY - centerY;
double angle=Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

g2d2.drawLine(16, 16, (int)Math.floor(deltaX + Math.cos(angle)), (int)Math.floor(deltaY + Math.sin(angle)));
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have. I can't make it any shorter

Comment: Asked about SSCCE, not your original code, so you should create one SSCCE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Have a look at my skeletal answer.

Comment: `Graphics g2d2 = (Graphics)g;` you dont even need this cast. Why are you casting back to the same type ? :D

Comment: *"I have."*  No you haven't. *"I can't make it any shorter"*  Your attention span?  If you had a longer attention span, you might have noticed that there are 5 letters in SSCCE.  Your uncompilable code snippet corresponds to just the first - 'Short'.  Now try to make an example that conforms to the *other parts.*

Comment: @AndrewThompson Look, I tried to post everything that I needed to without any unnecessary code.

Comment: *"..without any unnecessary code"*  An SSCCE of a run-time problem needs to include imports and a `main(String[] args)`.  It needs to compile cleanly as copy/pasted.  What you posted does not do any of that.

Comment: @AndrewThompson How's that?

Comment: That is ..sad, really.  Sad that you cannot get this simple concept.  Try copy/pasting that rubbish and compiling it yourself.  Does it compile without errors?  Can it be run to see the problem?  Have you even ***read*** the document on the SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I'm just trying to find an answer to a math question, there is obviously something wrong with the math, so I was thinking you wouldn't even need to compile it to find the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It was easier for me to write an SSCCE for the OP. Have a look at the answer :-D

Comment: @LittleChild  I liked the pre. edit comment better.  ;)  Nice SSCCE, BTW, but I cannot up-vote again.  They only give me one turn at it!  :-(

Comment: @AndrewThompson HAHA ! I thought that was a little harsh so I edited that out :-P

Comment: @LittleChild  I suspected as much.  ;)  OTOH I'm not sure if it is actually possible to offend an Aussie.  Our skin is just too thick.  E.G. If a person goes around town trashing our name, we tend to think "Huhh.. it's nice they're thinking of me!".

Comment: @AndrewThompson I guess if I begin with a `Mr. Andrew [rant]` and add some high-school teacher rant there, I am sure you are going to be fuming like a hot kettle :-D

Answer (score 2):

Ok, pick a point on the screen of your application. Say, the center. mark that point as the anchor.

Now, add a `MouseMotionListener` to your screen and look for whenever the mouse is moved. You need this point to draw a line. The first point being the anchor.
Now, call `repaint()` every time the mouse moves.

In the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` , use the `g.drawLine(anchorX,anchorY,mouseX,mouseY)` to draw the line. Since `paint()` is called before `repaint()`, you need to give some initial value to these 4 variables.

**SSCCE:**

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class LineFollower extends JFrame{

        int anchorX = 0;
        int anchorY = 0;
        int mouseX = 0;
        int mouseY = 0;

        JPanel canvas = new JPanel(){

                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(500, 500);
                }

                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                        super.paintComponent();
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY, mouseX, mouseY);
                }
        };

        public LineFollower(){
                anchorX = 500 / 2;
                anchorY = 500 / 2;

                this.getContentPane().add(canvas);
                this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                canvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                                mouseX = e.getX();
                                mouseY = e.getY();
                                repaint();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                                mouseX = e.getX();
                                mouseY = e.getY();
                                repaint();
                        }
                });
                this.pack();
                //this.setSize(500,500);
                this.setVisible(true);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                new LineFollower();
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

Comment: @Cj1m Then all you need to do is use my method :) Much simpler, no trigonometry.

Comment: That doesn't work either, it gives the same results as the code before.

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918732/using-jpanel-to-draw-straight-lines-and-get-point-coordinates/14918871#14918871

Comment: I do not have experience developing games. Sorry =)

Comment: No, not make a game, just do the thing with the player how it points towards the mouse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39557/discussion-between-cj1m-and-little-child)

Comment: would you be able to go on the chat link I sent you?

Comment: Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()`.

Comment: @mKorbel Done !! I must blame `ivor Horton` for getting the override `paint()` in my head :-D

Comment: +1 now better, please to move any listener later added to JPanel, to the JPanel ...